# Open pdf using android intents with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, android-intent

Using an Android phone, when i click on a pdf link (i.e. example.com/abc.pdf), Chrome downloads it. I want Chrome to directly open it with the default pdf viewer of the user. So i think i need to use:

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

I do not want to force user to open it with a specific app (i.e. adobe reader) so i do not know the package name.

Any help?

If it is not possible, how to open it with adobe reader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many hours of trying...and at last...

```
<a href="intent://example.com/abc.pdf#Intent;scheme=http;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end">open pdf</a>
```